# OneTimeSetUp runs only once for a parameterized test fixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I created a test fixture that is parameterized with a pair of string values and includes several test methods. Parameters are passed to test class constructor. I expect that each instance of the fixture is created with a specific pair of string parameters and then all tests in it are run. Initialization that is common for all tests in the fixture is done in a method decorated with `OneTimeSetUp` and finalization is done in `OneTimeTearDown`:

```
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(MyFixtureData), "FixtureParameters")]
public class MyModuleTests
{
private string parameter1;
private string parameter2;

public MyModuleTests(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{
    this.parameter1 = parameter1;
    this.paramter2 = paramter2;
}

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void InitializeFixture()
{
// perform initialization steps: create test objects, run browser, open test page, check that required objects exist on page etc.
}

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void FinalizeFixture()
{
    // perform finalization steps: close browser etc.
}

[Test]
public void MyModuleTest1()
{
    // assert something
}

[Test]
public void MyModuleTest2()
{
    // assert something
}

[Test]
public void MyModuleTest3()
{
    // assert something
}

public class MyFixtureData
{
    public static IEnumerable FixtureParameters
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestFixtureData("string value1a", "string value1b");
            yield return new TestFixtureData("string value2a", "string value2b");
            yield return new TestFixtureData("string value3a", "string value3b");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` methods are run only once, however I expect them to run for every fixture instance (three instances in my case).

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you running tests? I am wondering if you may be using a runner of some kind that bypasses the NUnit code and prevents it's creation of multiple instances.

Comment: If any NUnit-provided runner is not creating an instance for each TestFixtureSource returned, then please report a bug.

Comment: Charlie, I did some research and found the cause - it is `Close()` method invoked on a WebDriver instance in `OneTimeTearDown` section that disposes the instance and the tests in consequent fixtures (they are actually created) fail immediately in Test Explorer. I commented out that `Close()` method and all fixtures worked. However, now I'm struggling with the problem of closing the browser after all fixtures are completed.

Comment: But still I don't understand why even after closing the WebDriver instance, the new fixture instance's `OneTimeSetUp` does not create everything from scratch? The error message is:

Message: OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:52911